# Recursive type encoding on System F (and other pure type systems)

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I am studying pure type systems, particularly the calculus of constructions, and trying to use an encoding for recursive types on it, which, [according to Philip Wadler, is possible](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free-rectypes/free-rectypes.txt). As an example, I'm using the [Morte Haskell library](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Morte-Library) to encode [Scott numerals as given by Cardelli](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/Notes/scott2.pdf).

A summary of the encoding is as such: given a (positive) recursive type...

$$\mu X.F\ X$$

...we may encode it as a type on System F as...

$$Lfix\ X.F\ X\ =\ \Lambda X.(F\ X\rightarrow X)\rightarrow X$$

...or, using pure type systems' notation (with an explicit $F$)...

$$Lfix\ =\ \Pi F: *\rightarrow*.\Pi X: *.(F\ X\rightarrow X)\rightarrow X$$

...since $F$ is a type constructor ($*$ is the type of types).

In order to encode such, we need to declare three functions, $fold$, $in$ and $out$, according to Wadler, and used by Cardelli on the encoding for Scott numerals.

> fold  :  All X. (F X -> X) -> T -> X
>
> fold  =  \X. \k: F X -> X. \t:T. t X k
>
> in    :  F T -> T
>
> in    =  \s: F T. \X. \k: F X -> X. k (F (fold X k) s).

(Where $T$ is $Lfix\ X. F\ X$.)

It's trivial to write the $fold$ function as given. But when trying to write the $in$ function, it doesn't seem to typecheck. The expression $(fold\ X\ k)$ has type $T\rightarrow X$, and $(F\ (fold\ X\ k)\ s)$ should be of type $F\ X$. Then we infer that $F$ should be of type $(T\rightarrow X)\rightarrow F\ T\rightarrow F\ X$ (looks like a `fmap`). This doesn't typecheck, because `F` is a type constructor (of type $*\rightarrow*$).

[This doesn't look like a typo](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Esweirich/types/archive/1999-2003/msg00138.html)... am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a convention in category theory that the same symbol is used for a type constructor and the map function over that type constructor. Hence, if f : X -> Y then F f : F X -> F Y.

Comment: So it is indeed a `fmap`! I got zero experience on category theory, but I actually found that about 10 minutes ago on "A note on Categorical Datatypes" (G. C. Wralth). I was now able to write the correct function, worked like a charm. Thank you very much, dr. Wadler! :D